# Can I put commands after Form.Close()?

Tags: c#, winforms

In C#,
Suppose I am in a form, and I pressed a button I made to close it.

```
this.Close();
some_action(); //can I do this??
```

can I perform another action after I closed the form or does the thread die and everything after that is lost?

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to do and the context of the statement. If the form being closed is the main form which owns the message loop, you can't do any **UI related stuff** (e.g. you can't display another `MessageBox`). If you are not doing it from another window (which doesn't own the message loop), you could do anything (even UI related) as long as you aren't manipulating the closed form object (you'll get `ObjectDisposedException` just like any disposed object).

By the way, the thread doesn't die as a result of `Close`. Closing the main window causes the message loop to terminate and not the thread itself. For example, the following program

```
static void Main() {
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}
```

will display `Form2` after `Form1` is closed (using a newly created message loop). This proves that the thread is not dead.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to manipulate the form or any of it's controls after calling Close you're going to run into trouble. However there's nothing preventing you from calling some other method - for instance a logging method - after calling Close.

Answer (score 1):

Handle [FormClosing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) and do additional action in event handler.